# React Native: How to read and display xml file

Tags: react-native

How can I display the .xml file to the screen. I can display the pdf file using `react-native-pdf` but how can I display the text in .XML file or read it.

Comment: have you considered sharing your approach? although I'm posting an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**solution to <del>display the text in .XML file or</del> read it**

I'm showing you how can you read any file. If you can read any file, storing that to some state, then rendering is not an issue, I hope so.

Here is how to read a local file in react-native :

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker';

selectFiles = () => {
    let that = this;
    try {
        DocumentPicker.pickMultiple({
            type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
        }).then((results) => {
            console.log(results[0]);
            //that.setState({language: results[0].type});
            RNFS.readFile(results[0].uri)
                .then((file) => {
                    that.setState({
                        code: file
                    });
                })
                .catch((error) => console.log('err: ' + error));
                //the `code` state holds your xml file, just display it however you want... use 3rd party library for syntax highlight or whatever you want
        });
    } catch (err) {
        if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
            // User cancelled the picker, exit any dialogs or menus and move on
        } else {
            throw err;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: WOW, this is so useful. Thanks a lot

Comment: This is working for all the file types. Thanks buddy